# Keras Embedding layer output dimensionality

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am confused with the output dimensions specified in the embedding layer in this code snippet

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, SimpleRNN

max_features = 10000
maxlen = 500
batch_size = 32

print('Loading data...')
(input_train, y_train), (input_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)

print(len(input_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(input_test), 'test sequences')
print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')

input_train = sequence.pad_sequences(input_train, maxlen=maxlen)
input_test = sequence.pad_sequences(input_test, maxlen=maxlen)

print('input_train shape:', input_train.shape)
print('input_test shape:', input_test.shape)

print(input_train)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 32))
model.add(SimpleRNN(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

Since the max_features is 10000, shouldn't the Embedding have an output dimensionality of 10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_features` is the number of words, not the dimensionality. In your embedding layer you have 10000 words that are each represented as an embedding with dimension 32.

Answer (score 1):

The output dimensionality of the embedding is the dimension of the tensor you use to represent each word. In your case, you use a 32-dimensional tensor to represent each of the 10k word you might get in your dataset.